# Error Handling in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to handle errors in Express.js?

For example, if user calls **non-existing resource**?

Answer (score 9):

If you want to yield a `404` just add this as your last route:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.send('Not Found', 404);
});
```

So everything that wasn't handled by any other route will results in a 404.

You can find additional information on sending error responses in the section of the expressJS API Reference that covers the send method of the Response object. It is located [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.send).

Comment: Thank you Ivo, but what if user calls `TRACE /whatever HTTP/1.1`? How do I handle this? Because at this time Express supports only `POST`, `GET`, `DELETE` and `PUT` methods.

Comment: @Omen I believe a user(browser) can't call TRACE? only a developer can and he should be reading the documentation you provide.

Comment: @OmenJugatar or you can always write a direct listener for it :P

Answer (score 8):

Omen, if you want to cover all [HTTP methods](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) use:

```
app.all('*', function(req, res) {

   // Do something...

});
```